# How to make a recovery persist through ROM installations?

Tags: rom-flashing, custom-roms, root-access, recovery-mode

1. It is very common for the recovery to be installed as part of the
   ROM installation, but is it possible to prevent the recovery from
   being changed during such a process?
2. If yes, are there any potential issues with doing so?

Comment: I have never installed a ROM that did anything with the recovery. What ROM is this? I would be very dubious about a ROM, especially if you are installing it through the recovery in the first place, changing the recovery. You could end up properly bricking the device. Is it the Bootloader you mean maybe?

Comment: No, I do mean recovery... Many ROMS in fact! However the only one that comes to mind at the moment is Vivek ROM

Comment: Wow, that's nuts. I've been flashing ROMs for many years now across about 12 different devices and never was the recovery included in the ROM. However, I always flash the ROM through the recovery itself and not through a program on the computer, so that may be a factor. If the recovery comes bundled you could in theory not flash it (depends on the PC program, file structure of each ROM though). The danger is the recovery included has scripts and interprets commands the ROM needs and it may fail installation without the correct recovery and brick the device.

Comment: Actually, I had flashed Vivek ROM on my samsung galaxy SII using the clockworkmod touch recovery (6.0.4.3 I beleive) only to find that after the first reboot it entered into a much older version of clockworkmod when i enter recovery mode!

Comment: Cool, thanks for the infomation, I did not know that at all. Good information. I'll have to defer the answer to someone more experienced on that. I must be using ROMs/Devices that don't do this, or I'm THAT blind to my recovery being changed! I have found a few ROMs lately that will only work with an older (or newer) version of recovery so I have to flash that version before the ROM, I guess including it with the ROM avoids this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I have not used Vivek ROM and I don't know how the ROM installation is happening. Most of the latest ROM now having AROMA Installer. So when installing the ROM, it will prompt whether you want to change recovery. So when you choose a new the ROM for your mobile, please check ROM installation is through AROMA installer and it has the option to flash recovery or not

Comment: I am aware of AROMA installer but this is not an ideal solution as it does not account for all other ROMs that don't use AROMA. You are right Vivek ROM does not use AROMA (it is a simplistic zip flash) but is there a way I can modify the zip so that the recovery does not get flashed? (If so, are there any consequences of not using its native recovery?)

Comment: No, you can remove without unzipping file.

Comment: Could you please elaborate? How can I do so?

Comment: I hope you downloaded the ROM from xda-forum. Its better to ask the same forum for getting help.